# How remove duplicates from a stored procedure without using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

A stored procedure has been written that includes duplicates. ROW_NUMBER was tried but did not work. `DISTINCT` has worked but was unable to retrieve the large number of records required (about 700,000). Is there another way of using RANK or GROUP BY to remove duplicates?

I have used DISTINCT and this does not retrieve enough records. I have not successfully used GROUP BY.

I have attempted to use ROW NUMBER but this did not work either (you can see where its commented out).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [report].[get_foodDetails] 
    @foodgroup_id INT, 
    @shop_id INT = 0, 
    @product_id INT = 0, 
    @maxrows INT = 600, 
    @expiry INT = 1, 
    @productactive INT = 1, 
    @expiryPeriod DATETIME = '9999-12-31 23:59:59' 
AS 
    IF (@expiryPeriod >= '9999-12-31') 
    BEGIN 
        SET @expiryPeriod = GETDATE() 
    END 

    SELECT  
        -- dp.RowNumber 
        ISNULL([FoodType], '') AS [Foodtype],
        ISNULL([FoodColour], '') AS [FoodColour],
        ISNULL([FoodBarcode], '') AS [FoodBarcode],
        ISNULL([FoodArticleNum], 0) AS [FoodArticleNum],
        ISNULL([FoodShelfLife, '9999-21-31') AS [FoodShelfLIFe]
    INTO 
        #devfood 
    FROM 
        report.[GetOrderList] (@foodgroup_id, @product_id, @productactive, @expiry, @expiryPeriod, @shop_id, @maxrows ) dp 
    INNER JOIN 
        food_group fg ON fg.food_group_id = it.item_FK_item_group_id 

    SELECT TOP(@maxrows) * 
    FROM #devfood 
    ORDER BY [device_packet_created_date]  
 END
```

Around 700,000 records retrieved. This is currently achieved although there are duplicates. There are only 20,000 retrieved when using DISTINCT (but no duplicates).

Comment: I don't understand the issue with `select distinct`.  Perhaps you could explain it with some test data?

Comment: It works but will only retrieve 20,000 records. I need 700,000

Comment: how many 'distinct' records are there?  could there be 680,000 duplicate records?  DISTINCT will only return each single instance of the fields in your select, if there are duplicate rows without DISTINCT, then DISTINCT will suppress them all

Comment: when you say you need 700,000 you mean there are 700,000 distinct records? and you are receiving only 20,000 of them?

Comment: I receive 20,000 records within a given date range when using DISTINCT. I can see in the database there are more records (non-duplicates in the database for this date range). DISTINCT cut it off at 20,000. Even with out the duplicates I would anticipate well over 400,000 records.

Comment: DISTINCT will not exclude any rows that are in fact unique unless you are not selecting the columns that make the row unique. Are you returning all columns?

Comment: I see that you have a parameter @maxrows, which limits the number of rows returned. Double check the values which you are using to call the procedure (the order of the parameters may be different, so you may have used another value by mistake).

Comment: The @maxrows parameter is also used in the GetOrderList function, so the number of rows may be limited there (before the DISTINCT is applied).

Comment: If you want to demonstrate how this doesn't work, I'd recommend creating a small table with a handfull of rows that demonstrates your problem, and include the results in your question. Will make it easy for others to debug what you are doing. Its not clear here.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code below is from a presentation I've used to demonstrate CTE's. This is a common mechanism for removing duplicates and is very fast. In this case the duplicates are removed directly from the table. If that is not your objective you could use a temp table or a prior chained CTE. Note that the important thing is what columns you partition by. If, in the example, you partitioned by only [name] you would not see both the red rose and the white rose.

```
-------------------------------------------------
if object_id(N'[flower].[order]', N'U') is not null
  drop table [flower].[order];

go

create table [flower].[order]
  (
     [id]       int identity(1, 1) not null constraint [flower.order.id.clustered_primary_key] primary key clustered
     , [flower] nvarchar(128)
     , [color]  nvarchar(128)
     , [count]  int
  );

go

insert into [flower].[order]
            ([flower]
             , [color]
             , [count])
values      (N'rose',N'red',5),
            (N'rose',N'red',3),
            (N'rose',N'white',2),
            (N'rose',N'red',1),
            (N'rose',N'red',9),
            (N'marigold',N'yellow',2),
            (N'marigold',N'yellow',9),
            (N'marigold',N'yellow',4),
            (N'chamomile',N'amber',9),
            (N'chamomile',N'amber',4),
            (N'lily',N'white',12);

go

select [flower]
       , [color]
from   [flower].[order];

go

--
-------------------------------------------------
with [duplicate_finder]([name], [color], [sequence])
     as (select [flower]
                , [color]
                , row_number()
                    over (
                      partition by [flower], [color]
                      order by [flower] desc) as [sequence]
         from   [flower].[order])
delete from [duplicate_finder]
where  [sequence] > 1;

--
-- no duplicates
-------------------------------------------------
select [flower]
       , [color]
from   [flower].[order];
```

Comment: In my opinion it's hard to recommend this as solution in general case. Chain of CREATE-INSERT-DELETE-SELECT looks too heavy. If you want to demonstrate CTE - you can substitute `DELETE` for `NOT EXISTS` clause

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried `ROW_NUMBER`, but did you try it either of these ways?

First, a `CTE`. The `CTE` here is just your existing query, but with a `ROW_NUMBER` windowing function attached. For each duplicate iteration of a record, it will add one to `RowNumber`. With the next unique group of records, `RowNumber` resets to `1`.

After the pull, only take the records with a `RowNumber = 1`. I use this all the time for deleting dupes out of the underlying record set, but it works well to just identify them as well.

```
WITH NoDupes AS
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                           ISNULL(FoodType, '')
                          ,ISNULL(FoodColour, '')
                          ,ISNULL(FoodBarcode, '')
                          ,ISNULL(FoodArticleNum, '')
                          ,ISNULL(FoodShelfLife, '9999-21-31')
                         ORDER BY
                           (
                             SELECT
                               0
                           )
                        ) AS RowNumber
     ,ISNULL(FoodType, '') AS Foodtype
     ,ISNULL(FoodColour, '') AS FoodColour
     ,ISNULL(FoodBarcode, '') AS FoodBarcode
     ,ISNULL(FoodArticleNum, 0) AS FoodArticleNum
     ,ISNULL(FoodShelfLife, '9999-21-31') AS FoodShelfLIFe
    FROM
      report.GetOrderList(@foodgroup_id, @product_id, @productactive, @expiry, @expiryPeriod, @shop_id, @maxrows) AS dp
    INNER JOIN
      food_group AS fg
        ON
        fg.food_group_id = it.item_FK_item_group_id
  )
SELECT
  nd.Foodtype
 ,nd.FoodColour
 ,nd.FoodBarcode
 ,nd.FoodArticleNum
 ,nd.FoodShelfLIFe
INTO
  #devfood
FROM
  NoDupes AS nd
WHERE
  NoDupes.RowNumber = 1;
```

Alternatively (and shorter) you could try `SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES`, using that same `ROW_NUMBER` function to order the record set. The `TOP (1) WITH TIES` part functionally does the same thing as the `CTE`, returning only the first record of each set of duplicates.

```
SELECT
  TOP (1) WITH TIES
  ISNULL(FoodType, '') AS Foodtype
 ,ISNULL(FoodColour, '') AS FoodColour
 ,ISNULL(FoodBarcode, '') AS FoodBarcode
 ,ISNULL(FoodArticleNum, 0) AS FoodArticleNum
 ,ISNULL(FoodShelfLife, '9999-21-31') AS FoodShelfLIFe
INTO
  #devfood
FROM
  report.GetOrderList(@foodgroup_id, @product_id, @productactive, @expiry, @expiryPeriod, @shop_id, @maxrows) AS dp
INNER JOIN
  food_group AS fg
    ON
    fg.food_group_id = it.item_FK_item_group_id
ORDER BY
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                       ISNULL(FoodType, '')
                      ,ISNULL(FoodColour, '')
                      ,ISNULL(FoodBarcode, '')
                      ,ISNULL(FoodArticleNum, '')
                      ,ISNULL(FoodShelfLife, '9999-21-31')
                     ORDER BY
                       (
                         SELECT
                           0
                       )
                    );
```

The `CTE` is maybe a little clearer in it's intention for the next person who looks at the code, but the `TOP` might perform a little better.

Comment: I tried the SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES solution, which works but only retrieves the same number of records as distinct (all non-duplicates) why would this create a ceiling on the number of records retrieved? Is there a way a GROUP BY would work